# Authorizations and Groups with Rails and CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have a User and an Organization model with a many-to-many association, via a Membership model. Users (there are no roles) should only be able to create, read, and update Organizations to which they belong as members.

I've put the following in from CanCanCan's Ability class and have a   `load_and_authorize_resource` on the Organization model.

```
can [:create, :read, :update], Organization do |organization|
    !(organization.memberships & user.memberships).empty?
end
```

When I load /organizations (index page), `@organizations` is nil.

When I set `@organizations = Article.accessible_by(current_ability)` I get the following error:

> The accessible_by call cannot be used with a block 'can' definition.
>   The SQL cannot be determined for :index Organization(id:integer...

The [docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#fetching-records) mention advice to use SQL, but I don't quite understand how.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line was part of the problem.

```
!(organization.memberships & user.memberships).empty?
```

I went with the version below which appears simpler and correct.

```
organization.memberships.pluck(:user_id).include?(user.id)
```

The error remains when calling `accessible_by(current_ability)` with a block, but I was able to workaround with Devise's `current_user` method.